# Using random to set a value and prevent the value to be given again?

Tags: batch-file

I am making a small script that would assign roles as an app sort of thing. It asks for the number of people, then it runs random to see what role you are.
Like this:

```
:mrole
set/a player1=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %player1%==1 set 1role=Murderer
```

But what if I only want a certain ratio of people to get a certain role? Say 1:4 are murderers. If I do something like this for up to 8 players what if 6 of them are murderers? What if I want to run through again for a Detective role if there are 8 people? The current one I have for mrole is 29 lines! Is there a quicker way than checking if there are too many EVERY time? And the Detective check is going to be very long too!

What I have so far is below and here's a link: http://pastebin.com/g2GfN7v9

```
@echo off

:new
set test=2

:main
cls
echo Trouble in Murder Town
echo --------------------------
echo.
echo 1. Start
echo 2. Tester Options
echo 3. Quit
echo.
set/p m=
if %m%==1 goto start
if %m%==2 goto testrat
if %m%==3 exit
goto main

:testrat
cls
echo Chance to have a tester
echo -----------------------
echo Currently a 1 in %test% chance to have a tester in a game
echo.
echo 1. Always
echo 2. Never
echo 3. 1/2 (default)
echo 4. 1/3
echo 5. 1/4
echo 6. 1/5
echo 7. Back
echo.
set/p t=
if %t%==1 set test=1
if %t%==2 set test=0
if %t%==3 set test=2
if %t%==4 set test=3
if %t%==5 set test=4
if %t%==6 set test=5
if %t%==7 goto options
goto testrat

:start
cls
echo How many players not including the one at the computer?
echo.
echo 1. 3
echo 2. 4
echo 3. 5
echo 4. 6
echo 5. 7
echo 6. 8
echo 7. Quit
echo.
set/p t=
if %t%==1 set players=3
if %t%==2 set players=4
if %t%==3 set players=5
if %t%==4 set players=6
if %t%==5 set players=7
if %t%==6 set players=8
if %t%==1 goto names
if %t%==2 goto names
if %t%==3 goto names
if %t%==4 goto names
if %t%==5 goto names
if %t%==6 goto names
if %t%==7 goto main
goto start

:names
cls
echo Please enter their names.
echo.
set/p player1=Player 1: 
echo.
set/p player2=Player 2: 
echo.
set/p player3=Player 3: 
echo.
if %players%==8 (
    set/p player4=Player 4: 
    echo.
    set/p player5=Player 5: 
    echo.
    set/p player6=Player 6: 
    echo.
    set/p player7=Player 7: 
    echo.
    set/p player8=Player 8: 
    goto role
) else if %players%==7 (
    set/p player4=Player 4: 
    echo.
    set/p player5=Player 5: 
    echo.
    set/p player6=Player 6: 
    echo.
    set/p player7=Player 7: 
    goto role
) else if %players%==6 (
    set/p player4=Player 4: 
    echo.
    set/p player5=Player 5: 
    echo.
    set/p player6=Player 6: 
    goto role
) else if %players%==5 (
    set/p player4=Player 4: 
    echo.
    set/p player5=Player 5: 
    goto role
) else if %players%==4 (
    set/p player4=Player 4: 
    goto role
) else goto role

:role
set 1role=0
set 2role=0
set 3role=0
set 4role=0
set 5role=0
set 6role=0
set 7role=0
set 8role=0
set murderers=0
set detectives=0
goto mrole

:mrole
set/a player1=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %player1%==1 set 1role=Murderer
if %player1%==1 set/a murderers=%murderers% + 1
if %player1%==1 set mcheck=y
if %player1% neq 1 set mcheck=n
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
set/a player2=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player2%==1 set 2role=Murderer
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
set/a player3=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player3%==1 set 3role=Murderer
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
set/a player4=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player4%==1 set 4role=Murderer
set/a player5=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player5%==1 set 5role=Murderer
set/a player6=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player6%==1 set 6role=Murderer
set/a player7=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player7%==1 set 7role=Murderer
set/a player8=%random% * 4 / 32768 + 1
if %mcheck%==y if %players% lss 8 goto drole
if %murderers%==1 if %players%==8 if %player8%==1 set 8role=Murderer
if %murderers% lss 1 goto mrole
if %players%==8 if %murderers% lss 2 goto mrole

:drole
if %players%==8 (

) else if %players lss 8 goto irole

:irole
if 1role==0 set 1role=Innocent
if 2role==0 set 2role=Innocent
if 3role==0 set 3role=Innocent
if 4role==0 set 4role=Innocent
if 5role==0 set 5role=Innocent
if 6role==0 set 6role=Innocent
if 7role==0 set 7role=Innocent
if 8role==0 set 8role=Innocent
```

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you're looking for is a shuffle.  Think of your roles as a deck
of cards, with one role per card.  If you were playing a game with people, you'd
shuffle the deck of roles and hand one card to each person.

Study the following code that declares a deck of 4 cards and then shuffles them.
I've named the deck in the style of an array from more traditional programming
languages, but it's really just a convention.  I could have named it in the
form of `DECK.1, DECK.2, ...` or whatever.

I've also isolated parts of the program into subroutines.  There's a subroutine
to generate a random number, print an "array", shuffle an array, and swap 2
items in an array.  When working with array-style indirection in batch, you'll
hit a wall if you don't break things into subroutines.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "DECK[0]=1H"
set "DECK[1]=2S"
set "DECK[2]=3C"
set "DECK[3]=4D"
set "DECK_SIZE=4"

call :print_array "DECK" %DECK_SIZE%
call :shuffle "DECK" %DECK_SIZE%
echo -----
call :print_array "DECK" %DECK_SIZE%

goto :eof

REM Generate random number from %1 min through %2 max.
:rand
set /a RAND_NUM=%RANDOM% * (%~2 - %~1 + 1) / 32768 + %~1
goto :eof

REM %1 Name of array to print
REM %2 Size of the array
:print_array
set /a LAST_INDEX=%~2-1
for /L %%a in (0, 1, %LAST_INDEX%) do (
    echo %~1[%%a]: !%~1[%%a]!
)
goto :eof

rem To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
rem   for i from n − 1 downto 1 do
rem        j ← random integer with 0 ≤ j ≤ i
rem        exchange a[j] and a[i]

REM %1 Name of array to shuffle
REM %2 Size of the array
:shuffle
set /a LAST_INDEX=%~2-1
for /L %%a in (0, 1, %LAST_INDEX%) do (
    call :rand %%a %LAST_INDEX%
    call :swap "%~1[%%a]" "%~1[!RAND_NUM!]"
)
goto :eof

REM %1 One of the variables to swap.
REM %2 The other variable to swap.
:swap
set "__tmp=!%~1!"
set "%~1=!%~2!"
set "%~2=!__tmp!"
goto :eof
```

So to modify this code for your program, you'd want an array of players and an
array of roles.  The player array remains fixed, and you shuffle the role array.

E.g.,

```
set "PLAYER[0]=Howard"
set "PLAYER[1]=Fred"
set "PLAYER[2]=Robin"
set "PLAYER[3]=Gary"
set PLAYER_SIZE=4

set "ROLE[0]=murderer"
set "ROLE[1]=innocent"
set "ROLE[2]=innocent"
set "ROLE[3]=detective"
set "ROLE_SIZE=4"

call :shuffle "ROLE" %ROLE_SIZE%
set /a ROLE_LAST_INDEX=%ROLE_SIZE%-1
for /L %%a in (0, 1, %ROLE_LAST_INDEX%) do (
    echo Player !PLAYER[%%a]! is !ROLE[%%a]!.
)
```

One sample output from this code would give you:

```
Player Howard is detective.
Player Fred is innocent.
Player Robin is murderer.
Player Gary is innocent.
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

SET "roles=1234"
SET players=4
:setplayrole
SET /a player=1+(%RANDOM% %% %players%)
IF DEFINED $%player% GOTO setplayrole
SET $%player%=%roles:~-1%&SET "roles=%roles:~0,-1%"
IF DEFINED roles GOTO setplayrole

SET $

GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a snippet that might achieve your aim.

But first, a little commercial - you have tis line in your posting:

```
if %player1%==1 set 1role=Murderer
```

Um - it's *possible* to do this, but a really, really bad idea because of batch's syntax. Never start a variablename with a numeric. It has huge consequences, and none of the are good.

--- back to our - er, program...

I'm not clear whether your difficulty is assigning the ratios of roles to the players, but it seems that you want a proportion in each role; guaranteed there are no 'no-one playing this role'.

To me, what you'd do is assign a set of `roles` - I've just use 1..4 with an even distribution. You may want to have 10 players, one each in roles 1..4 and the others random, where you could build the `roles` string by appending the `random` roles to a seed of required roles.

Having established the set of roles for the game, you then assign each role in the string to a player, and remove the role as it is assigned.

I use a standard `clear out all variables with names starting "$"'` routine; then assign the required roles, (append any extras as you wish) then the loop is simple - select a random player; if that player already has an assigned role, select again. If not, simply assign the last role in the list and remove the last role entry. Continue until the `roles` list is empty, and all done...